# Condição Four/While em linguagem M - Paginar API no Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, dax

Olá,
Preciso de uma ajuda para implementar um laço de four/while na minha api.
Criei esta API paginada abaixo, funciona corretamente, mas na propriedade OFFSET, preciso estipular o próximo numero da sequencia, quando a API vai para a pagina 2,3, etc. Por exemplo, na pagina 1, o Offset=0, entao funciona perfeito, porém quando vou para a pagina 2, o offset deveria ser 250 (limite maximo de registros por pagina, estou usando esse limite), no entanto, do modo que esta abaixo, esta sendo enviado o numero 2, sendo assim, na pagina 2, os registros veem todos duplicados, e isso acontece sucessivamente até terminar o looping em todas paginas.

Código:

```
let
        ufnCallAPI = (offSet) =>
            let
                query = Web.Contents("https://api.vhsys.com/v2/pedidos?offset=" & Number.ToText(offSet)  &  "&limit=250", 
                [Headers=[#"access-token"="OCKNYbAMaDgLBZBSQPCOGPWOXGSbdO", #"secret-access-token"="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"]]),
                result = Json.Document(query)
            in
                result,

            tmpResult = ufnCallAPI(1),

            auxTotal1 = Record.ToTable(tmpResult),
            Value = auxTotal1{2}[Value],
            auxTotal2 = Value[total],
            totalItems = auxTotal2 -1,
            pageRange = {0..Number.RoundUp(totalItems / 250)},

            pages =List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(_)),
            pages2 = Table.FromList(pages, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
            pages3 = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(pages2, "Column1", {"code", "status", "paging", "data"}, {"Column1.code", "Column1.status", "Column1.paging", "Column1.data"}),
            pages4 = Table.ExpandListColumn(pages3, "Column1.data"),
            pages5 = Table.RemoveColumns(pages4,{"Column1.code", "Column1.status", "Column1.paging"}),
            data = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(pages5, "Column1.data", {"id_ped", "id_pedido", "id_cliente", "nome_cliente", "id_local_retirada", "id_local_cobranca", "vendedor_pedido", "vendedor_pedido_id", "listapreco_produtos", "valor_total_produtos", "desconto_pedido", "desconto_pedido_porc", "peso_total_nota", "peso_total_nota_liq", "frete_pedido", "valor_total_nota", "valor_baseICMS", "valor_ICMS", "valor_baseST", "valor_ST", "valor_IPI", "condicao_pagamento_id", "condicao_pagamento", "frete_por_pedido", "transportadora_pedido", "id_transportadora", "data_pedido", "prazo_entrega", "referencia_pedido", "obs_pedido", "obs_interno_pedido", "status_pedido", "contas_pedido", "comissao_pedido", "estoque_pedido", "ordemc_emitido", "data_cad_pedido", "data_mod_pedido", "id_aplicativo", "id_pedido_aplicativo", "lixeira"}, {"id_ped", "id_pedido", "id_cliente", "nome_cliente", "id_local_retirada", "id_local_cobranca", "vendedor_pedido", "vendedor_pedido_id", "listapreco_produtos", "valor_total_produtos", "desconto_pedido", "desconto_pedido_porc", "peso_total_nota", "peso_total_nota_liq", "frete_pedido", "valor_total_nota", "valor_baseICMS", "valor_ICMS", "valor_baseST", "valor_ST", "valor_IPI", "condicao_pagamento_id", "condicao_pagamento", "frete_por_pedido", "transportadora_pedido", "id_transportadora", "data_pedido", "prazo_entrega", "referencia_pedido", "obs_pedido", "obs_interno_pedido", "status_pedido", "contas_pedido", "comissao_pedido", "estoque_pedido", "ordemc_emitido", "data_cad_pedido", "data_mod_pedido", "id_aplicativo", "id_pedido_aplicativo", "lixeira"}),
        #"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(data,{{"id_ped", type text}, {"id_pedido", Int64.Type}, {"nome_cliente", type text}, {"valor_total_produtos", type text}}),
        #"Valor Substituído" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Tipo Alterado",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"valor_total_produtos"}),
        #"Tipo Alterado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Valor Substituído",{{"valor_total_produtos", Currency.Type}}),
        #"Valor Substituído1" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Tipo Alterado1",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"desconto_pedido", "desconto_pedido_porc", "peso_total_nota", "peso_total_nota_liq", "frete_pedido", "valor_total_nota", "valor_baseICMS", "valor_ICMS", "valor_baseST", "valor_ST", "valor_IPI"}),
        #"Tipo Alterado2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Valor Substituído1",{{"desconto_pedido", Currency.Type}, {"desconto_pedido_porc", Currency.Type}, {"peso_total_nota", Currency.Type}, {"peso_total_nota_liq", Currency.Type}, {"frete_pedido", Currency.Type}, {"valor_total_nota", type text}, {"valor_baseICMS", Currency.Type}, {"valor_ICMS", Currency.Type}, {"valor_baseST", Currency.Type}, {"valor_ST", Currency.Type}, {"valor_IPI", Currency.Type}, {"prazo_entrega", type text}, {"data_pedido", type date}}),
        #"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Tipo Alterado2",{"id_aplicativo", "id_pedido_aplicativo", "lixeira"}),
        #"Tipo Alterado3" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Colunas Removidas",{{"valor_total_nota", type text}}),
        #"Valor Substituído2" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Tipo Alterado3",".",",",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"valor_total_nota"}),
    #"Tipo Alterado4" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Valor Substituído2",{{"valor_total_nota", Currency.Type}})

    in
    #"Tipo Alterado4"
```

Preciso alterar esta linha para incluir four/while no item "ufnCallAPI (_)",:

pages = List.Transform (pageRange, each ufnCallAPI (_)),

por exemplo, do item acima deveria ficar asim:

```
List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(_)) - (esse caso esta certo, pois na primeira interação é passo o 0 corretamente),
List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(250)),
List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(500)),
List.Transform(pageRange, each ufnCallAPI(750)),
```

até o número total = totalItems

Preciso entao, incluir uma condição de four/while para modificar minha API para não passar o número do primeiro item da página seguinte (offset), porém já tentei de várias formas, e não tenho experiência com M. Alguma ideia por favor?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado com esse post: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-Query-M-function-in-Paginate-API/m-p/1091882

Obrigado.